# Question on application of Tonelli's theorem in convolution (topological groups)

Tags: measure-theory

Let $G$ be a locally compact group which is a countable union of compact subsets and $\lambda$ a left Haar measure on $G$ (i.e. $(G,\lambda)$ is $\sigma$-finite). Let $f,g \in L^1(G)$. Then I have a question on the following application of Tonelli/Fubini: $$\int_G \int_G |f(y)||g(y^{-1}x)|d\lambda(y)d\lambda(x)=\int_G \int_G |f(y)||g(y^{-1}x)|d\lambda(x)d\lambda(y)$$ Why is this legitimate? I do not quite see why $|f(y)||g(y^{-1}x)|$ is measurable which actually reduces to the question why the function of two variables $f(y)g(y^{-1}x)$ is measurable.

**Edit.** This can be found in the third edition of the book classical fourier analysis by Loukas Grafakos, p. 20.

Comment: There is a remark on this on Rudin's "Real and complex analysis", when he speaks of convolution on $R^n$. I bet the same argument works in the general case.

Comment: Thanks for your remark. Where do I find this exactly? I have the third edition and on page 170 he defines convolution on $\mathbb{R}$. Where is the remark for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: It must be there nearby. I forgot Rudin treats convolution on $R$ and relegates the case of $R^n$ to the exercises.

Comment: Without loss of generality, choose versions of $f,g$ which are Borel.  The map $(x,y) \mapsto y^{-1}x$ is jointly continuous, since we are in a topological group, hence jointly measurable.  Hence so is $(x,y) \mapsto g(y^{-1}x)$.  And the product of (jointly) measurable functions is (jointly) measurable.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot. Just to be sure: why exactly can I make the assumption that $f$ and $g$ are Borel? I do not quite see the w.l.o.g.

Comment: This is a standard fact from measure theory: if $\mathcal{B}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{B}'$ is its completion with respect to some measure $\mu$, then for any real-valued $\mathcal{B}'$-measurable function $f$, there is a $\mathcal{B}$-measurable function $f_0$ with $f=f_0$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.  In particular they would represent the same element of $L^1$.

Comment: @NateEldrege: I am not sure that the continuity suffices.  For this you would need to know that the product sigma algebra on $G \times G $ is identical to the Borel sigma algebra on $G \times G $. This is true if $G $ is 2nd countable,  but can fail in general IIRC.

Comment: By the way, the remark on Rudin's book is exactly the same as @NateEldredge 's. There are some more details on Folland's "Real Analysis", second edition, pag. 240 (and Exercise 5, pag.245). This exercise, in particular, directly shows that $(x, y)\mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ is Lebesgue measurable whenever $f, g$ are, without passing from the Borel sigma algebra, so it might apply to the general case of $G$ not being second countable also. (HTH)